# Show graph without label, possible?

Tags: excel, vba, data-visualization

I have a macro that produces graphs like this:
[image]

The data for the graphs looks like `(100,0,0,94,0,132,0,126,115)` and so on.

The dotted graph shows all the data (note the dots on the "floor", that's data with value 0). The lines connects the dots with values more than 0.

I have to do this using two graphs and it works but it's a bit messy at the bottom as two labels show for each color. The example above works ok but if you want to see more lines it gets really messy quick and hard to see. Is it possible to only show the dotted graph in the graph window but not the corresponding label? Basically I want one label per color at the bottom.

And yes, I know there's a graph with dots and lines but it doesn't work for me.
Since the data looks like `(100,0,0,94,0,132,0,126,115)` the lines looks like sawtooths going all the way back to 0 and then back up again. I want the lines to only show the data with value more than zero.

Comment: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?51453-Problem-with-Deleting-Select-Legend-Keys

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the simplest way would be to substitute all 0 values with =NA() function.  Excel won't chart #N/A! values. You'll still see the category label in the axis, but Excel won't chart the actual zeros.

Comment: Tried to change all the zeros to #NA! but didn't get it to work. Not sure if I did it right. I changed the data type to variant and swapped all zeros with "#NA!".

Comment: @Jens Use find and replace to replace zeros with "=NA()", with a function, not with "#N/A!"